# Horizontal Navigation Bar Issues

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am currently re-working a website that I manage and I am having issues with the navigation bar. It works perfectly using a high resolution (I am currently using 1440x900), but when I switch to a lower resolution, the last couple menu items get chopped off.

Here is the HTML:

```
     <body>

<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="inside">


        <div id="header">
            <img src="LogoGood.gif" alt="LogoGood" width="591" height="224" />



        <div id="nav">
<ul>

    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="writings.html">Writing</a></li>
    <li><NOBR><a href="media.html">Media Relations</a></NOBR></li>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    <li><NOBR><a href="proofreading.html">Proofreading</a><NOBR></li>
    <li><NOBR><a href="work.html">Writing Workshops</a></NOBR></li>
    <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">Working With You</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutkathy.html">About Kathy Mayer</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Kathy</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
    #page-wrap {
background: beige;
min-width: 780px;
max-width: 1260px;
margin: 10px auto;
}
#page-wrap #inside {
    margin: 50px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

    #main-content {
background: beige;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 80px;

height: 400px;}


    #header {
padding-top: 5px;
background: beige;
text-align: center;}

    #nav {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: beige;
height: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255,23,28);}

    #nav ul{
text-align: center;
float: left;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 13px;
margin: auto;}

    #nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;}


    #nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 8px;
border-right: 1px solid rgb(255,23,28);}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your code is incomplete, where's the styling for the `li` elements? Also, could you post a working example on jsfiddle? (And better not use <nobr> use css white-space:nowrap instead...)

Comment: If elements get chopped off, it probably has something to do with the "overflow" property set to hidden. A working example would definitely help, but take a look in that direction.

Comment: @FrankParent I deleted the overflow:hidden CSS and reloaded the page and changed my resolution. The menu items were there this time, but on the next line. Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main problem here is the number of menu items present and the defined height. The items are there, but the height of `#nav` is just `80px`. For wider screens, this shouldn't be a problem, but for screens with smaller resolution, the menu will get chopped off, especially when the height is already defined. One top of that, having a lot of items in a single navigation bar surely increases its overall width. Having long names for links also help increase the width of each `li` (for example, "About Kathy Mayer" compared to "About" or "About Me" and "Contact Kathy" compared to "Contact").

One way of getting rid of this problem is by creating two separate navigation bars. You may have "Home", "About/About Kathy Mayer" and "Contact/Contact Kathy" on the top-right corner of the page, making it a separate nav-bar, and keeping the rest on another nav-bar, so that you'll have two different navigation bar.

Another way would be making a vertical navigation bar, which will eliminate the whole problem.

One more idea I just got: You may also sub-menus for items that have similar titles, like enlisting "Writing", "Proofreading" and "Workshops" under one sub-menu.

I hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your `#page-wrap` to `min-width:780px` - but your menu is wider than that.

http://jsfiddle.net/bbcmF/

Try a larger min-width: http://jsfiddle.net/bbcmF/1/ (or make the menu smaller)

Comment: Changing the min-width didn't fix the issue, nor did making the menu smaller. Making the width of the menu smaller just cut off the rest of the menu items that exceeded that width. Any other suggestions?